# How to display a small dot on top of a ionic component

Tags: css, sass, ionic4

How to display a small css circle on top of an ionic component(ie a date).the calendar component what i tried is as following.But round circle is not comming on top of a number.

```
  button.days-btn.my-cal.marked {

       content: '\25CF';
  font-size:25px !important;
  color:green !important;
  }
```

Comment: did you try using ion-badge? It will make it by itself .

Comment: Checkout https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/badge

Comment: Do you mean that you have a calendar and you need to put a circle on top the selected/current date?